# ConvertTo-SecureString how to use use password from file

Tags: windows, powershell, encryption

I would like to use encrypted credentials to log in to domain (without admin interference)i Found below script to encrypt password. I will deploy file with encrypted password to machines

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'P@ssw0rd' -AsPlainText -Force |Out-File "C:\Temp\Password.txt"
$secureString = Get-Content "C:\Temp\Password.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$User = "MyUserName"
$File = "C:\Temp\Password.txt"
$MyCredential=New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, (Get-Content $File | ConvertTo-SecureString)
```

I would like to use variable "$MyCredential" that stores User and encrypted password in file then join to domain uses that. Not sure how.

Comment: Are you deploying it directly from the script? If so, why place the password into a txt file?

Comment: I want to hide password from the user, i will send encrypted password in .txt file and script to join to domain

Comment: I think this article gives a full run out, I've used it myself: https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/04/21/using-saved-credentials-securely-in-powershell-scripts/ Just a quick heads, generating a secure password on one computer cannot be used on another, you'll have to see the other ways in the link provided

Comment: @I.TDelinquent You can write a secure string to a file on one computer and read it from that file on another, but that requires using a shared secret on both computers (via the parameter `-Key`, as mentioned in the comments to that article).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers That's what I was referencing to, I probably could have worded my comment a bit better :) I meant that the current way provided in the question would have to be changed to what is outlined in the article.

Comment: I think i am unable to do that, computer is out of domain at different location, that is why i want to do this this way...

Comment: What OS version do the target machines run?  I have a wholly different approach to your problem that might work very easily.

Comment: @I.TDelinquent Ah, sorry then. That wasn't clear to me, since you referred to the article itself, and from what I saw it's not mentioned there.

Comment: OS is win10 machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a totally different approach to your question, given that these machines are running Windows 10, you can create MDM Enrollment Packages using [Windows Image Configuration and Designer (WICD)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-configuration-designer/9nblggh4tx22?rtc=1&activetab=pivot:overviewtab), which can contain instructions to enroll a machine on a domain.

The user experience would be that you distribute the file (WICD generates a `.PPKG` or provisioning package file type, which Windows 8.1 and up can natively use), either by a thumbdrive or e-mail, or another method, and then someone double-clicks the file and it would seemlessly enroll the device in the domain from there.

#### How to create a domain enrollment package

Launch WICD then choose 'Advanced Provisioning' from the bottom of the list of options.  Provide a path to save the file.

Next, expand out to this path **Runtime Settings\Accounts\ComputerAccount**

[image]

The minimum settings you'll need to provide are:

- DomainName - Name of the domain to join
- Account - Account with domain join perms
- Password - Password of the above account
- AccountOU (optional) - the OU into which the device should be placed after enrollment

When this is done, you'll see the following in the column on the right.

[image]

Finally, export the Package by clicking **Export \ Provisioning Package**.  A word of caution, the password will be obfuscated within the provisioning package, but a very determined assailant could recover the PW.

#### Optional configurations you might like

If you have the means, you could optionally Sign the package, if your target machines trust a certificate you can issue, for added convenience.  If you use this route, the enrollment will be completely silent and the user will not have to click 'Accept'.  [I provide details on doing that in this blog post.](https://foxdeploy.com/2017/06/05/the-quest-for-true-silent-mdm-enrollment/#more-4859)

If you don't Sign the package, a user will have to click 'OK', as shown in this screenshot.

[image]
If you choose to apply Encryption to the package, you'll need to also come up with a share the password to your target users.  This adds extra security to the contents of the package.

I know this is different than you originally asked, but in my mind and experience, this is the safest and most professional way you could approach enrolling existing machines into your environment safely and securely.

Comment: Seems legit , I will check tomorrow at work , thanks